# Espresso how to wait for recyclerview to load its items from a server call

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I have a list that is populated with data from a call to a server. But the time differs alot for different users. How can i wait with espresso for my list to be populated before i start clicking the cells.

Comment: just do an asynctask and wait until it finish, if you want more help please post some of your code

Comment: i use rxjava not asyncTasks